# Difference in the Knockout.js binding between Chrome/Firefox/Safari vs Internet Explorer

Tags: knockout.js

I noticed a difference between how the Knockout.js observable binding works in Chrome/Firefox/Safari vs Internet Explorer 9.

I have tried this both in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/ and from the Knockout.js web at http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html.

In Internet Explorer 9 I have to leave the fields to see the change, but in Chrome/Firefox/Safari I can just press enter to see the change.

Is this how it suppose to be or is there a bug somewhere? I would like it to be like in Chrome/Firefox/Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the computed value to be shown as you type in IE, as it does in Chrome / Safari / FF, you need to bind the valueUpdate property of the data-bind to afterkeydown, like so:

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
  <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p> 
  <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p> 
  <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>  
</div>
```